# Adding an array and an object to an array react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add an array and an object to an array.

This is my constructor

```
const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState({ loading: true, data: [], address: '' })
```

and this is how I wanted the data to end up

```
{
   loading: true,
   data: [{id: 0, name: 'A'}, {id: 1, name: 'B'}],
   address: 'xxx'
}
```

I can't seem to figure it out and was only able to manage to add the arrays but not the other objects like `loading` and `address` with something like this but this is not what I need and I'm just giving an example of what I tried doing:

the constructor of this one in the bottom is different from what I want to use, I used something like this

```
const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState([])

setDashboard((prev) => {
   return [...prev, newData]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you are trying to do something like this:

```
setDashbaord(prevDashboard => ({ ...prevDashboard, address: "xxx", data: [...prevDashboard.data, newData] }));
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: YES!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState({ loading: true, data: [], address: '' })
```

The line above looks great, no problems there.

```js
setDashboard((prev) => {
   return [...prev, newData]
})
```

Doing this will set your `dashboard` variable to be an array, and is definitely not what you said you wanted.

```
setDashboard((prev) => {
  return {
    ...prev,
    data: [...prev.data, ...newData] // <-- assuming new data is an array
  }
})
```

Depending on what `newData` looks like you may need to manually merge the data into your previous data object. For instance, if you want to ensure you have no duplicate values in the array, or you need to sort them.

Comment: yessss you got it right! thank you! <3